# np.piecewise generates incorrect values for integer array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, piecewise

I have a numpy piecewise function defined as

```
def function(x):
    return np.piecewise(x, [x <= 1, x > 1], [lambda x: 1/2*np.sin((x-1)**2), lambda x:-1/2*np.sin((x-1)**2)])
```

I have no idea why this function is returning incorrect values for various x-values. In particular, running the following

```
X = np.array([0,2.1])
Y = np.array([0,2])
A = function(X)
B = function(Y)
```

will give A = array([ 0.42073549, -0.467808  ]), but B = array([0, 0]). Why is this happening?

I am expecting B = array([0.42073549, -0.468ish]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the types of your data.

`X` is an array of floats. But `Y` is an array of int.

And, quoting documentation of `piecewise`

> The output is the same shape and type as x

So, output of `piecewise` when called with `Y`, that is an array of shape (2,) and dtype `int64`, is forced to be an array of shape (2,) and dtype `int64`. And the closest `int64` to `0.42073549, -0.468ish` are 0 and 0.

Just replace Y by `np.array([0,2.0])` (to force float type), or `np.array([0, 2], dtype=np.float64)`,

Comment: how did i not see/realize this. youre good